# Basic Data Warehouse - How to join data 2 tables away

Tags: mysql, join, data-warehouse

I have a basic data warehouse setup that represents the police force:
[image: Data warehouse for the police department]

Every `FACT_CRIME` has an assigned `DIM_OFFICER`; every `DIM_OFFICER` is assigned to a `DIM_STATION`.

What SQL logic can I use to display all `FACT_CRIME`s along with the associated `DIM_STATION`? My issue is that to obtain the `DIM_STATION`.`station_code`, I know it must be done via the `DIM_OFFICER`, since that is the relational link, but I'm not savvy enough with SQL to know how to get data from 2 tables away.

This is a query I have so far, it produces the format I'm after, but not the correct results:

```
select
    fact_crime.*, dim_station.station_code
from fact_crime
join dim_station
    on fact_crime.assigned_officer_id
        in (select dim_officer.officer_id from dim_officer where dim_officer.station_id = dim_station.station_id)
group by dim_station.station_code
```

Sample of produced results: (correct format, but incorrect data)
[image: Sample of produced results]

I'm expecting every instance of `FACT_CRIME` to appear, with the assigned officer's station code additionally appearing in the table.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can point me in the right direction. I'm still trying to get to grips with the basics of SQL, so apologies if I require additional clarification on any responses.

Comment: 90% of the information provided here is redundant to the problem at hand. Please see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Hi Ollie Was looking at the dimensional model.. Just a suggestion on this.. This model looks heavily 'snow flaked'..If possible please convert the model to a snow flake design if possible...For eg:Dim_Location could contain Dim_City and Dim_County details..Dim_Convict could be joined directly to the Fact_Crime rather than Dim_Conviction..Dim_Crime could be joined directly to Fact_Crime.. j

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two joins, someting like this (I'm guessing because you didn't show many details).

```
...
from fact_crime c
join dim_officer o ON c.assigned_officer_id = o.officer_id
join dim_station s ON o.station_id = s.station_id
```

This is a very common SQL pattern, so you'll find the MySQL software does a good job making it efficient.

**Pro tip**: Avoid the `*` in `SELECT *`, especially from result sets that are results of lots of `JOIN` operations. Instead, use `SELECT` to give the list of columns you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction - this seems to be giving the correct results! Could you possibly explain how the double join is different from the ON + nested select statement?